# "Add to Watch" chrome keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know a way of adding a keyboard shortcut to the "Add to Watch" from chrome devtools?

I have tried to tinker with some addons that can add keyboard shortcuts to chrome but none had the "Add to Watch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ctrl+shift+A"

Src: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234954

Tested in chrome 47 and it works.

Comment: No two-modifier combinations (plus A) work in Chrome 87 (ca. 2021) on Mac. I even went as far as unmapping `Shift + Option + a` from Dark Reader... Wouldn't it be nice, though?